# Почему строки с fuzzy в django.po не переводятся?

Tags: python, локализация, django

Я обновляю файл django.po таким образом:

```
$ python manage.py makemessages -l ru
$ python manage.py compilemessages -l ru
```

После этого часть строк в django.po помечаются как fuzzy и не переводятся во время работы приложения. Например, при

```
#, fuzzy
msgid "view"
msgstr "показ"
```

вместо показ будет view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

При выполнении `makemessage` как `fuzzy` помечаются строки имеющие близкий `msgid`. Такие строки не попадают в итоговый `*.mo` из `*.po`, как предположительно неверные. Нужно их поправить и убрать пометку `fuzzy`.